# CakephpTwo different login function

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I have a classic login page in my cakephp application, where user enter his login and password.
For the authentication I have make a custom login function.

I want make a second authentication function because I want my user be able to connect into the application when they click on a link in an other application. This second application will send the username (no password). I will checked if he have the right to login and automatically login him in the home page of the application.

I have thinking of making the href link on a specific page who will done this login and redirect user to the home page.

I hope all is clear. Can you give me your help, and tell me how do you do that.
The existing login function look like this :

```
//AppController.php
function beforeFilter(){
     $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Ldap');
     $this->Auth->authorize = array('Controller');       
}
public function isAuthorized(){
    $user = $this->Auth->user();
    if($user) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;   
}



//Controller/Component/Auth/LdapAuthenticate.php
App::uses('BaseAuthenticate', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class LdapAuthenticate extends BaseAuthenticate {
public function authenticate(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response) {
    $username=$request->data["Users"]["username"];
    $pwd=$request->data["Users"]["password"];
    $ldap = ldap_connect("***************");
    ldap_set_option ($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
    ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

    $bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, "WORLD\\".$username, $pwd);
    if ($bind && $pwd!="") {
        $ldap_dn ="DC=world";
        $filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=".$username.")(cn=*))";
        $justthese = array("cn","mail","givenname","distinguishedname","memberof");
        $sr=ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn, $filter,$justthese);
        $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $sr);
        ldap_close($ldap);
        return $info;
    } else {
        ldap_close($ldap);
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It should be similar when somebody logged in by a remember me cookie.

Comment: you can add role field in your users table and check in if role has  regular user or admin or whatever your requirement.and then redirect to their location

Comment: I don't want adding role to my application, but have an other login fonction who is independent from the first one. This authentication will be without password and redirect to a different page